# Fill column in R data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I need to fill columns in new data.table according to names of columns from another.

In one table are col names a,b,c in second are names a_1, a_2, b_2, b_1 ... I need to fill all columns in second table from values from 1st table and put same data to all columns containing a or b or (all same part) in column names.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```r
table_1[, setNames(.SD, names(table_2)), .SDcols=sub("_.*", "", names(table_2))]
#     a_52  b_25   c_1   d_k   F_z  a_23  b_28  c_21  d_25  F_25
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     1     1     1    20     1     1     1     1    20
# 2:     2     2     2     2    21     2     2     2     2    21
# 3:     3     3     3     3    22     3     3     3     3    22
# 4:     4     4     4     4    23     4     4     4     4    23
```

---

Data

```r
table_1 <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(a = 1:4, b = 1:4, c = 1:4, d = 1:4, F = 20:23), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
table_2 <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(a_52 = logical(0), b_25 = logical(0), c_1 = logical(0), d_k = logical(0), F_z = logical(0), a_23 = logical(0), b_28 = logical(0), c_21 = logical(0), d_25 = logical(0), F_25 = logical(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```